# Is it bad practice to call MobX action on React component lifecycle methods

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, mobx, mobx-react

I have async action, that fetches data from API and merges it with collection in store, triggering appropriate computeds to reevaluate and populate the view back.

My previous solution was to have @async-computed that will include trigger variable in it s body (not used for anything else than triggering recalculation unfortunately) and also populate the view.

Am happy with @computed-async -> @async action refactor but one last obstacle I met makes me wander.

While @computeds gets calculated first time when I reach for them for the first time, @action needs to be called explicitly.

I can not call it in store constructor as it will not be testable so the only place I can is componentDidMount or WillMount in React component. 
AFAIK it s better to do it in componentDidMount out of performance reasons. 
But (!) is it OK, to explicitly call action in React life cycle methods? Or should I consider it bad practice?

Up to now, I was rather avoiding it, but this one case seems to be way better handled with @async-action and I would like to stick to it as long as am not breaking any larger design pattern that will blow back in my face in future.

Thanks!

Comment: up? up up up up up?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by it won't be testable? If the component needs data from the io/store to display, can you use stubs to provide didn't data?

See this article for more: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-decouple-state-and-ui-a-k-a-you-dont-need-componentwillmount-cc90b787aa37

Comment: my @action is fetch with parameter (quantity of items to fetch from server). I can not call it in constructor explicitly with fixed parameter value because in tests it will always call that particular fetch with that particular value whenever I create the store. That is not testable. - what if I want to fetch different quantity from API or test if passing 0 fetches nothing? If code is in constructor I can not do it in clean manner. Constructors should not have side effects - ex. API calls.

Comment: I think in testing you'll have to separate the fetching itself (which is part of a store, right?) and how the fetched data is used in the component. In the link I posted, the fetching is called by the router.